# how to read a file from HDFS through browser

Tags: hadoop

How to provide a link a HDFS file, so that clicking on that url it will downlaod the HDFS file..

Please provide me the inputs..

Thanks
MRK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [HDFS Proxy Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/hdfsproxy.html).

There is also [Hoop](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/07/hoop-hadoop-hdfs-over-http/) which is being [contributed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2178) to Hadoop by Cloudera. Currently it's targeted for the 0.24 release. But, it can be build, installed and configured manually using the instructions at the [Hoop Site](http://cloudera.github.com/hoop).

While HDFS Proxy supports only W, HOOP supports R/W to HDFS. Plan is to replace HDFS Proxy with Hoop.

While the above options are proxy based, another option is to to directly access the NameNode without a proxy. Browse the file system (http://namenode:50070/nn_browsedfscontent.jsp) and go to the file for which the URL has to be shared.

Edit: Also check [WebHDFS](http://hortonworks.com/webhdfs-%E2%80%93-http-rest-access-to-hdfs/).

Comment: Note, "Hoop" has now been renamed to HttpFS - https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/HttpFS+Installation

Comment: http://namenode:50070/nn_browsedfscontent.jsp was the easy answer for what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you have hue installed in your cluster you could try

http://www.namenode:8888/filebrowser

or they also have standard chrome extension at this link that will basically covert the hdfs link for you

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Simple+Chrome+Extension+to+browse+HDFS+volumes

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Hue File Browser](http://gethue.com/demo-hdfs-file-operations-made-easy-with-hue/): upload/download files, list directories, change permissions, view directly different types of file... from any client with a Web Browser