# How to use HDFS in a web application to store uploaded images and display them on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, hadoop, hdfs

I have a JSP web application and I would like to store images uploaded by users in HDFS and then display the image in JSP front end page on an image tag. I have looked all over the internet but there is oddly not a single example for this particular task. Most code snippets either show the word count Map-Reduce functionality, how to write to and open a file from the FS but not how to display it on a web page.

This is the basic flow of my application.

1. User uploads a file from web html form

   ```
   <form action="profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="photo" value=""/>    
      <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
   </form>
   ```
2. Servlet receives request and writes the file to local file system using the apache [FileUpload 1.2.2](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) library. Which raises the question, how can I write the incoming stream directly to HDFS without saving to the local FS first?

   ```
   @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
          String userPath = request.getServletPath();
          if (userPath.equals("/profile")) {

              if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
   //            create a new file upload handler
              ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
   //            parse the request
              FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
              InputStream stream = null;

             while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                  FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
                  stream = item.openStream();
                  if (!item.isFormField()) {
                   File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "images/" + item.getName());

                   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   Streams.copy(stream, fos, true);

     //            copy from local FS to HDFS
                   ...

                }
         }
   }
   ```
3. Copy uploaded image from local filesystem to HDFS

   ```
   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
   config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
   FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config); 

   //       For illustration purpose lets call the uploaded file bee.jpg  

   fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("file:///home/qualebs/NetBeansProjects/qualebs/build/web/images/bee.jpg"), new Path("bee.jpg"));
   out.close();
   ```

**And finally the question**
Normally to display the uploaded image to a JSP page one would just use the image tag like

```
<img src="images/bee.jpg"/>
```

How do I display this image when it's in Hadoop?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `HDFS`. It's about how to 'publish' the image directory into the internet... and that depends on your infrastructure, e.g. Apache HTTP, storage layout, and so on...

Comment: @home I am really new to this and I only have a single node set up. Is there no more help I can get. An example would be nice.

Comment: You must configure your web server to 'publish' the image path. An example a servlet is here (there might be better ways): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps

Comment: Note that HDFS is not designed for small files in large number, but other way.

Comment: @Praveeen Sripati so I have read but I think I've got that covered by something I read about Sequence Files in this question stackoverflow.com/questions/16546040 I hope that is all I need to address the many small files issue. Also from the answer you gave to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209616/how-to-read-a-file-from-hdfs-through-browser, can I use HTTPFS for my use case here?